# Get an specific class field content from the same page (Javascript or PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I would like to get the content of an specific div class in Javascript or PHP. I've found some possible solutions but no one worked for me. This is the code of the page:

```
<div class="um-field um-field-professional_tag um-field-text" data-key="professional_tag">
   <div class="um-field-label"><label for="professional_tag-27326">Professional Tag</label>
   <div class="um-clear"></div></div>
       <div class="um-field-area">
       <div class="um-field-value">text_to_be_retrieved</div>
</div></div>
```

The required content is the one containing "**text_to_be_retrieved**" but the code shall not be aware of the text "text_to_be_retrieved" (**it has to retrieve the text just with the surrounding divs information**). Is it possible to store it in a PHP/Javascript variable to be used by another algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unable to make out anything from your question..Are you asking to find element having text as `"adolfodominguez"` ?

Comment: I'd like to get the content of the element (in this case "adolfodominguez")

Comment: What do you want to store ?

Comment: I'd like to store in a variable the containing text of the div (text_to_be_retrieved)

Comment: Unable to guess your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, store those values in object:

```js
var obj = {};
var nick = $('.um-field-label label').attr('for');
var val = $('.um-field-label').next('.um-field-area').find('.um-field-value').text();
obj.nickName = nick;
obj.value = val;
alert(obj.nickName + " " + obj.value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="um-field um-field-nickname um-field-text" data-key="nickname">
  <div class="um-field-label">
    <label for="nickname-27326">Professional Tag</label>
    <div class="um-clear">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">adolfodominguez</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes.. but that's the point, I don't know the value. It has to be as generic as possible..

Comment: Sorry, but I think I didn't explained it properly. The structure of the page is always as shown in my code. The only thing that changes every time is the text "adolfodominguez". With the rest of the structure of the page, I'd need to get this info (I am not able to know the content, only the surrounding structure).
So for instance, knowing the previous div label (nickname-27326) and knowing that the next div is the one that has the needed field I could retrieve this information.

Comment: Don't know if I still get it, but if you don't need that label stored, you can remove that, and store only the field value. check the edit

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that is what I was looking for. The only thing (and maybe that's the reason because it's not working for me) is that there is more than one "um-field-label", so that the code does not found the correct one in the first time. Is there anyway to find the one with the label "nickname-27326"?

Comment: You can find it like this : `var val=$('.um-field-label label[for*=27326]').parent().next('.um-field-area').find('.um-field-value').text();`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to find elements that contains specified 'text'

If you have a variable holding the text wrapped in div, you can pass the variable in `:contains`

Try this:

```js
var myText = 'adolfodominguez'; // Variable holding text value
var element = $('.um-field-value:contains("' + myText + '")')
console.log(element);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="um-field um-field-nickname um-field-text" data-key="nickname">
  <div class="um-field-label">
    <label for="nickname-27326">Professional Tag</label>
    <div class="um-clear">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">adolfodominguez</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code shouldn't be aware of the text "adolfodominguez", it should retrieve this value without the containing text information.

Comment: The variable with the containing text "adolfodominguez" shall be the last step in the code (that's the aim of the algorithm). The point is: without knowing the content, is it possible to retrieve it? (using the surrounding divs information).

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML, I appended an element to show you the output.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="um-field um-field-professional_tag um-field-text" data-key="professional_tag">
    <div class="um-field-label">
        <label for="professional_tag-27326">Professional Tag</label>
        <div class="um-clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="um-field-area">
        <div class="um-field-value">adolfodominguez</div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>Copied text:
<p class='demo'></p>
```

Using the jQuery framework of Javascript, you will get the result you are looking for:

```
var text =  $("[for='professional_tag-27326']").parent('.um-field-label').next('.um-field-area').children('.um-field-value').text();
$('.demo').text(text);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/73mtmLLv/5/

Comment: Yes, thanks. It is similar to the answer below (@itsgoingdown). The only remaining thing is that "um-field-area" is not unique, so it has to be the one just next to the "um-field-label" with the label for="professional_tag-27326"